# Unexpected results for PHP script interacting with database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I prepare a method "`find`" in PHP script to execute some searching in my database.It always gives me a result unexpected because I search in something exist really in my database but it shows me "`bool(false)`".I didn't know where I make the mistake. This is my code for the method "find" and "`findfirst`"(for `findfirst` it's the same concept of find method).

```php
protected function _read($table,$params=[])
{
   $conditionString= '';
   $bind=[];
   $order='';
   $limit='';
//conditions
if(isset ($params['conditions']))
{
  if(is_array($params['conditions']))
  {
    foreach($params['conditions'] as $condition)
    {
      $conditionString.=' ' . $condition . ' AND';
    }
    $conditionString=trim($conditionString);
    $conditionString=rtrim($conditionString,' AND');

  }

  else {
  $conditionString= $params['conditions'];

  }

if($conditionString !=''){
 $conditionString=' Where' . $conditionString;
}

}
//bind
if (array_key_exists('bind',$params))
{
  $bind=$params['bind'];
}
//order
if (array_key_exists('order',$params))
{
  $order=' ORDER BY ' . $params['order'];
}


//limit
   if (array_key_exists('limit',$params))
{
  $limit=' LIMIT ' . $params['limit'];
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM {$table}{$conditionString}{$order}{$limit}";
if ($this->query($sql,$bind))
{
  if(!count($this->_result)) return false;
  return true;
}
return false;


}



public function find ($table ,$params=[])
{
if ($this->_read($table,$params)){
  return $this->results();
}
return false;
}

public function findfirst ($table ,$params=[])
{
  if ($this->_read($table,$params)){
  return $this->first();
}
return false;

}
```

and this is the code of home.php where i call the method "find" .

```php
$usersU=$db->find('users',[

'conditions'=>"username = ?",
'bind'=>['kh'],
'order'=>"username, password",
'limit'=>''
]);
```

and this the method "results" and "first".

```php
public function results(){

  return $this->_result;
}

 public function first(){

  return (!empty($this->_result)) ? $this->_result[0] : [];
}
```

this is the query method .

```html
public function query ($sql, $params = [])
{
$this->_error = false;
if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql))
{
  $x=1 ;
  if (count($params))
{
foreach ($params as $param)
{
  $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
  $x++;
}

}

if($this->_query->execute())
{

  $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
  $this->_lastInsertID =$this->_pdo->lastInsertId();

}
else
{
   $this->_error= true;
}

}
return $this;

}
```

Comment: add the find method so we will see the code... what are the final query? what is the unexpected result that you got?

Comment: "bool(false) " this is the unexpected result because i'm searching for something that really exist in my database .

Comment: what are the final query?   check what the error message...  you using PDO?

Comment: ther is no error message , i create in home a method that show the result of the query .The result in the screen is " bool(false)  " . i think i make mistake im the editing of  " _read function " or in the others functions .

Comment: you have 2 places that return false in method _read, please change and return "no result" as string in the if(query) part, and in the end ot the mthod return string "no query" ... just to understand witch of them are returned...

Comment: Print the produced SQL query and run it manually on the database to validate it.

Comment: i produce the SQL query and i run it on the database .It gives result .

Comment: if(!count($this->_result)) return false;  from this statement ,it appears that the result of the execution of the query is null .

Comment: i think we must see the full query, and please try to print the last query error message to be sure if thise query run successfully or not...

Comment: the query runs successfully on the database and have results but in the php script  didn't return anything .i will add the method query to the question ,i test it ,it works perfectly .

Comment: note: `if(!count($this->_result)) return false;` always use braces, always!

Comment: so ... what is the full query? please copy here... 

and please check what you have in the qeury errir ... see how in this link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: it not a problem using braces in this if statement .

Comment: Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT' at line 1 )

Comment: it shows me this error errorinfo()

Comment: great... we moving forward... what is the full query?

Comment: all information about the query is attached to the question

Comment: i don't see any sql query string in your post or comment, and i asked few times, so... i can't continue helping you until you will add here the full query "SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT ..."

Comment: @shushu304  u didn't understand the question from the beginning there is no full query statement , i trying to program a method that i put into it the conditions and some more details and it execute automatically a query to find what i m searching on it  .

Comment: it's ok i fixed now it was a problem of spaces her

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM {$table}{$conditionString}{$order}{$limit}";

Comment: the right one is like this

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM  {$table} {$conditionString} {$order} {$limit}";

Comment: adding spaces between {}

Comment: great... so i hope my question was helpful ... it's was for teach you that in the next time you got some unexpected result please check what is the full sql query string that you trying to execute ... and use the last error message.
You are welcome to mark "up" for my help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was solved by adding some spaces {$table}{$conditionString}{$order}{$limit}

Answer (score 0):

The following keyword `PASSWORD` *(MySQL is case-insensitive with regard to reserved keywords)* is a MySQL [Reserved Keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) and therefor must be quoted properly to be permitted as identifier.

**Example**

```
$usersU=$db->find('`users`',[    
'conditions'=>'`username` = ?',
'bind'=>['kh'],
'order'=>'`username`, `password`',
'limit'=>''
]);
```

Try the following. The error is because `$params['limit']` and `$params['order']` should not be empty in your if statements that create the query.

```
protected function _read($table,$params=[])
{
   $conditionString= '';
   $bind=[];
   $order='';
   $limit='';
//conditions
if(isset ($params['conditions']))
{
  if(is_array($params['conditions']))
  {
    foreach($params['conditions'] as $condition)
    {
      $conditionString.=' ' . $condition . ' AND';
    }
    $conditionString=trim($conditionString);
    $conditionString=rtrim($conditionString,' AND');

  }

  else {
  $conditionString= $params['conditions'];

  }

if($conditionString !=''){
 $conditionString=' Where ' . $conditionString;
}
}
//bind
if (array_key_exists('bind',$params))
{
  $bind=$params['bind'];
}
//order check that $params['order'] is not empty also
if (array_key_exists('order',$params) && !empty($params['order']))
{
  $order=' ORDER BY ' . $params['order'];
}

//limit check that $params['limit'] is not empty also
   if (array_key_exists('limit',$params) && !empty($params['limit']))
{
  $limit=' LIMIT ' . $params['limit'];
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM {$table}{$conditionString}{$order}{$limit}";
if ($this->query($sql,$bind))
{
  if(!count($this->_result)) return false;
  return true;
}
return false;      
}



public function find ($table ,$params=[])
{
if ($this->_read($table,$params)){
  return $this->results();
}
return false;
}

public function findfirst ($table ,$params=[])
{
  if ($this->_read($table,$params)){
  return $this->first();
}
return false;

}
```

Comment: it is not problem of quotes i think  the problem  in the SQL statement it shows me this error by using errorInfo()

Comment: Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 )

Comment: @miramohamed that is a parse error you are mixing single quotes and double quotes to create your query.

Comment: @miramohamed the error is a parse error, and is generated by the way the query is being created. Check the revised answer please you will understand.